# magento cms/page/layout drop down is empty after editing etc/local.xml

Tags: xml, e-commerce, magento-1.7, magento

Am trying to add a new layout `4column.xml` in `cms->pages->layout`

Am find this tutorial

http://www.crearegroup-ecommerce.co.uk/blog/magento-tutorials/create-new-layouts-for-your-template-pages.php

And implement it.

But it only shows **4column Layout**

So i remove the changes and clear the cache to showing the other layouts

Unfortunately in my **cms->pages->Design->layout**

**The drop down is empty**

How to fix this i want my default layouts

Please help me

**And nobody try the above link**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

i have encountered similar problem and  solving like this

in the `core folder`  copy this file ie `core\code\mage\page\etc\config.xml`

and override like this

```
core\code\mage\page\etc\config.xml
```

refresh the **cache**

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `layout_handle` node:

```
<global>
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <your_mod module="your_mod" translate="label">
                <label>Your Mod Custom Layout</label>
                <template>your_mod/custom_layout.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>custom_layout</layout_handle>
            </your_mod>
        <layouts>
    <page>
</global>
```

You can leave this in your *app/etc/local.xml* or you can create a new module which will build out the rest of the functionality by specifying a new layout update XML file in which you would have the following:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <your_mod>
            <class>Your_Mod_Helper</class><!-- if you are translating the label -->
        </your_mod>
    </helpers>
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <your_mod module="your_mod" translate="label">
                <label>Your Mod Custom Layout</label>
                <template>your_mod/custom_layout.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>custom_layout</layout_handle>
            </your_mod>
        <layouts>
    <page>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <your_mod module="Your_Mod">
                <file>your_mod/layout.xml</file>
            </your_mod>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <!-- if you are translating the label -->
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Your_Mod>
                <files>
                    <default>Your_Mod.csv</default>
                    <!-- ref app/locale/en_US for examples -->
                </files>
            </Your_Mod>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
```

And, finally, in *app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/your_mod/layout.xml*:

```
<!-- ref. to last handles in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml -->
<custom_layout translate="label">
    <label>Your Mod Custom Layout</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>your_mod/custom_layout.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
</custom_layout>
```

As near as I can tell this is an optimization which allows various areas of view calculation to have logic to set root block template without performing the work if it's already done.